# Firestore with Ionic5 not working on deployed iphone

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, google-cloud-firestore, ionic5

I have an Ionic 5 app with firestore and cordova.

In the browser, on Android and using livereload on IOS ( ionic cordova run ios --livereload) the app works as expected.

However, when I just build the app (cordova ionic build ios) and end up deploying it to my iphone, the app cannot connect to firebase. Unfortunately I don't have any logs, but a login and read collections don't provide any data.

Do I still need to put the firebase URL somewhere to allow the app to access the internet?

Thanks in advance.

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/broadcaster": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/header-color": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/open-native-settings": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.8.5",
    "@ionic/core": "^5.8.5",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^0.13.5",
    "@types/webgl2": "0.0.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "cordova-android": "9.1.0",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-broadcaster": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": "^0.11.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-headercolor": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.4.6",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
    "firebase": "^9.2.0",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.11",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.3",
    "@ionic/v4-migration-tslint": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-pico": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: You could get logs by running the app through Xcode

Comment: Unfortunately no firestore relevant logs appear there

Comment: I solved it, by downgrade following packages: 

"firebase": "^8.10.0",
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5"

Answer (score 0):

I think package `firestore` with version 9 is using ios and indexedDB to store something about the authentification. Then you must add this code :

```
    const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
      initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });
    }
    this.firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

See original answer : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/firebase-auth-in-sdk-9-does-not-work-on-ios-sim-or-devices/215362